# openldap + kerberos - unable to reach any KDC in realm

Tags: ldap, docker, kerberos, openldap, kdc

I have a ldap server + kerberos setup in a centos vm (running using boot2docker vm) And i am trying to use them for my web application authentication (from host - my macbook).

For authentication, i need to use the "GSSAPI" mechanism, not the simple bind. 'simple bind' is working perfectly, but the "GSSAPI" based approach is not working.

I am getting the following error whenever i try the "ldapwhoami" command (i ran 'kinit' before running ldapwhoami to make sure i have valid kerberos TGT)

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (unable to reach any KDC in realm DEV.EXAMPLE.COM, tried 1 KDC)
```

Please note that the LDAP server and the kerberos server side is working perfectly, means i tested them with things like "ldapsearch", "ldapwhoami" in the centos VM where i have my ldap server + kerberos setup, Its working fine. I am able to see proper output for them.

I am getting errors (above error) only when i try the same command from my laptop (client).

Note: even i created host principal (host/mymacbook.dev@DEV.EXAMPLE.COM) from my laptop and added it to my local krb5.keytab file using 'kadmin'.

Below are my client side configurations:

/etc/krb5.conf file in Client (macbook):

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm    = DEV.EXAMPLE.COM
  ticket_lifetime  = 24000
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc   = false

[realms]
  DEV.EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = d4dc7089282c
    admin_server = krb.example.com
  }

[domain_realm]
  .dev.example.com = DEV.EXAMPLE.COM
  dev.example.com = DEV.EXAMPLE.COM
  .example.com = DEV.EXAMPLE.COM
  example.com = DEV.EXAMPLE.COM

[appdefaults]
  pam = {
    debug           = false
    ticket_lifetime = 36000
    renew_lifetime  = 36000
    forwardable     = true
    krb4_convert    = false
  }

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmin.log
```

/etc/hosts file in Client (macbook):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.59.3    mymacbook.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost


192.168.59.103  ldapserver.example.com
192.168.59.103  d4dc7089282c
192.168.59.103  krb.example.com
```

192.168.59.103 is my boot2docker vm ip, and i am doing port forwarding from boot2docker vm to docker  image on all the default ports related to LDAP and kerberos ( 88, 389, 464 & 749)

Any idea why i am getting this error?

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (unable to reach any KDC in realm DEV.EXAMPLE.COM, tried 1 KDC)
```

is it related to DNS or something else? any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need multiple things to get a containerized KDC being reachable from the outside.

Lets assume you are using port 88 as that is the default and lets also assume your image was called *docker-kdc*.

1. Make sure your port 88 is exposed.

`EXPOSE 88`

2. Make sure your KDC daemon listens on that port. For the sake of this example, I am simply using the KDC as an entrypoint, you should be able to extrapolate if that wasn't applying for your specific example.

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/heimdal-servers/kdc", "--config-file=/etc/heimdal-kdc/kdc.conf", "-P 88"]`

3. When running the container, I am using port forwarding towards 48088. Note that the KDC uses both, **TCP and UDP**.

`docker run -d -h kdc --name kdc -p 48088:88/udp -p 48088:88 docker-kdc`

From this point on, your KDC should be reachable from within the host system.

---

=== *OSX Only* ===

4. Now given that you are using OSX (boot2docker -> VirtualBox), you will also need to setup port forwarding towards your OSX environment.

`VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "48088/tcp,tcp,127.0.0.1,48088,,48088"`

`VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "48088/udp,udp,127.0.0.1,48088,,48088"`

---

5. Get the IP address of your docker container if needed.

   - When using plain docker (on linux), you can simply use the loopback `127.0.0.1`.
   - When using boot2docker (on OSX), you will get that using: `boot2docker ip`
6. Prepare a minimal krb5.conf that makes use of the KDC. For the sake of this example, I am using a realm called EXAMPLE.COM on the domain example.com.
   Note that you will have to replace *IP* with the result of step 5.

> [libdefaults]
>
> ```
>     default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
>     noaddresses = true
> ```
>
> [realms]
>
> ```
>     EXAMPLE.COM = {
>             kdc = IP:48088
>             admin_server = IP:48088
>     }
> ```
>
> [domain_realm]
>
> ```
>     example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
>     .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
> ```

7. Now go ahead and test that configuration.

`export KRB5_CONF=PATH_TO_THE_KRB5.CONF_FILE_FROM_STEP_6`

`kinit test/foo.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM`

Since I had to do this for a project of mine, I packed it all into some little script that  might be helpful for your further research; 
https://github.com/tillt/docker-kdc

Comment: Thanks Till! enabling udp port in my docker image resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 6):

On MacOS the default client does not fall back to TCP. 
in your krb.conf prefix your kdc with `tcp/` to force the client to use TCP if your network blocks UPD traffic (As some network admins might do).

```
kdc = tcp/ds01.int.domain.com:88
```

Comment: Same on NixOS Linux. `kinit --version` gives `kinit (Heimdal 7.5.0)
Copyright 1995-2014 [...]`

Comment: Thanks! Spent the whole day trying, but with `tcp/` it works (OSX)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that **krb5.conf** file is in **/etc** directory. I had the same issue and had no firewall issues, still was getting the same error. Finally, I was able to fix the issue by moving the krb5.conf file to **/etc** directory.

Comment: ...or make sure that you `export KRB5_CONFIG=/some/place/some.krb5.conf` cf. http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html